# Angular 2 multiple Observables asynchronous Requests to JIRA REST API

Tags: rest, angular, jira, observable

Hello Guys i have the following problem:

I need to send multiple POST-Requets to my JIRA-Server to create Issues with their subtasks. This is my Code:

```
  this.js.createEpic().subscribe(res => {

  this.js.createWorkPackages(res.key, 'CR XYZ | v1.x | Setup - Template').subscribe(res => {

  })

  this.js.createWorkPackages(res.key, 'CR XYZ | v1.x | Implementation - Template').subscribe(res => {

  })

  this.js.createWorkPackages(res.key, 'CR XYZ | v1.x | Test Preparation - Template').subscribe(res => {

  })
```

The Problem is that the Requests dont finish in the Order as written. I know they are asynchronous. But in JIRA the Ticket order is dependent on, which ticket is first created. So i need excatly this order for my Tickets. Is there a possibility to do this? I dont wanna do the requests synchrounously, so that i call the 2nd Request, when the first is finished... That is taking a lot of time because i have a lot of subtaks.

Summaray: I want asynchronous Requests to JIRA but with the excact wanted Finishing-Order. Hope you can help me... Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Do you want to wait for each request to finish and then do something when the 3 requests are finished ?

Comment: I want that that the first request finishes before the second request. But the second request should not wait doing his work, while the first request is not finished. But when the second Request finished his work before request 1 is finised, he should wait till request 1 gives a response back. They should work parallel but the answers should come in row (as they called). Did you understand? I know i cant explain it xD

Comment: Honestly ... I didn't get anything :D

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to fire every request at the same time and wait for every request to finish, here's how you could do it :

```
let setup$ = this.js.createWorkPackages(res.key, 'CR XYZ | v1.x | Setup - Template');

let implementation$ = this.js.createWorkPackages(res.key, 'CR XYZ | v1.x | Implementation - Template');

let test$ = this.js.createWorkPackages(res.key, 'CR XYZ | v1.x | Test Preparation - Template');

// launch the 3 requests at the same time
// and wait for the 3 answers before doing anything
setup$
  .combineLatest(implementation$, test$)
  .map(values => {
    // you now have access to the result of every request
    const [setup, implementation, test] = values;

    console.log(
      setup,
      implementation,
      test
    );
  })
  .subscribe();
```

---

**Warning :**

Remember that Angular2 won't unsubscribe for you automatically (unless you use `async` pipe).

So you should save the `setup$....subscribe();` like that :

```
private requestSubscription: Subscription;

...

this.requestSubscription = setup$....subscribe();
```

And in your ngOnDestroy method call unsubscribe :

```
this.requestSubscription.unsubscribe();
```

**EDIT 1 :**
In response of the comment :

> Yes but the second Request will only start when, the first is completed. So we can't work paralell and save time..

No, both request will be fired at the same time and executed in parallel.

Here's a demo :

```js
let d1 = Math.floor(Date.now());

let r1 = Rx
  .Observable.of('First request response')
  .do(x => console.log('Starting request 1 (will take 2s)'))
  .delay(2000);
  
let r2 = Rx
  .Observable.of('Second request response')
  .do(x => console.log('Starting request 2 (will take 5s)'))
  .delay(5000);
  

r1.combineLatest(r2).map(([val1, val2]) => {
  let d2 = Math.floor(Date.now());
  
  console.log('Both request are now done');
  console.log('It took : ' + (d2 - d1) + ' ms in total');
  
  console.warn('Response from request 1 :');
  console.log(val1);
  console.warn('Response from request 2');
  console.log(val2);
}).subscribe();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.7/bundles/Rx.umd.js"></script>
```

[image]

As you can see in the result of the demo, both request starts with only 2ms time difference.

As the request 1 take 2s, and request 2 take 5s, we have a message 5s later saying that it's done.

So yes, both request are fired same time and we wait for both to finish.

Comment: First thank you for the answer,
I already tried that. The problem is still the same. Also in this case, the second POST-Request can be finished earlier than Request 1. And then the list in Jira will be so : Package 2 , Package 1. I want to fire the Requests at the same time, so they can work paralell. But Request 2 shoundt finished before Request 1. Holy man thats really ennoying to explain. But i even know if this is possible to make

Comment: Here, they're both fired at the same time and they won't be mixed up as you say. They'll be in that order.

Comment: Yes but the second Request will only start when, the first is completed. So we can't work paralell and save time...

Comment: @oeem1011 please see my `EDIT 1`, I made you a demo to prove that both requests are fired same time as you expect.

Comment: Okay, i agree they are starting at the same time. But what is happening When request 1 takes 5 Seconds and Request 2 takes only 2 seconds. 
Okay i know we wait for the Response and this will come when both are finished. But my Jira Server will create the Ticket of the 2nd Request first, becouse he is done after 2 Seconds. And after another 3 seconds the ticket 1 is created. The Response that i get is not so important for me. Important for me is, the order of requests that my JIRA-Server completes. I think you understand me better now. Maybe i cant resolve this problem only on client side?